# How to combine .decode('utf-8') and .format() in Python?

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email in Python that will be both encoded in `UTF-8` and will have a formatting (so each client will be greeted with his name etc.).

Here's my function responsible for sending email, simplified:

```py
def sendMail(recipient, recipientName):
    file = open('~/mail.txt'.format(name), 'r')
    data = file.read()
    msg = MIMEText(data.decode('utf-8'), 'html', 'utf-8') # <<<<
    file.close()
    mail = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(ip, port)
    mail.login(mailUser, mailPassword)
    mail.sendmail(mailHost, recipient, msg.as_string().format(recipientName)) # <<<<
    mail.quit()
```

And this is the [content of mail.txt file](https://pastebin.com/ACsUw5fZ).

Basically the relevant thing here are `3rd` and `7th` lines of function - the rest is related to mail sending and is working fine. If I don't use `.decode('utf-8')`, formatting is fine - but in turn the email is almost unreadable.

I tried `%` parameters and `f` parameters as well with no success - basically only `.format` doesn't pull any error besides not actually working.

Comment: Where is the email text? Do you know that the result of encoding and decoding completely depends on the input? So no input means we have no way of helping you?

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I don't think I understand. The email text is a .txt file in `/home/xtul/mails/`. I am able to send the mail - if I add `.decode('utf-8')` it's displayed properly, but my formatting is gone. If I delete it, my formatting is intact, but there are no special characters, as the email is send as ASCII.

Comment: Can you share content of the mail file? Or just the snippet that is supposed to be formatted with the username?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://pastebin.com/4E2wnZw6. It isn't the actual email, but it's something along these lines and it contains symbols that I need to have in my mail.

Comment: `open('...'.format())` looks wrong where the string doesn't have any formatting specifiers. I guess you actually have a dynamic file name.

Comment: Can you provide a dump of the resulting email?

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x still by any chance?

Comment: A trivial workaround is to switch the HTML to use entities instead of raw UTF-8 character codes. Then your contents are actually ASCII.

Comment: @tripleee I use Python 3. I will show the output of UTF-8 mail and formatted mail in a moment.

Comment: @tripleee here's mail contents - for some reason, after the weekend the formatted email won't send due to `KeyError: 'recipientName'`. https://i.imgur.com/4YTgzfg.png

Comment: @tripleee ok I got the formatted mail to work: https://i.imgur.com/VOCPnew.png

Comment: The source of the email message would make more sense to share than Outlook's rendering. As text, not images.

Comment: @tripleee Eh, here's pastebin with results. https://pastebin.com/GcqU9Fia

Comment: There are no email headers in that.

Comment: @tripleee ah sorry for the hassle. Here are the mails with headers and content: https://pastebin.com/4VfdmNrF

Comment: `Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"` is clearly wrong for UTF-8 format; they both have `Content-Type: text/html` even though the format is clearly not HTML.

Comment: @xtl msg.as_string() actaully returns the content in Mime text format. The contents would be base64 encoded right?

Comment: @tripleee I see that `charset` is `"utf-8"` in the unformatted mail.

Comment: Yeah but the format is not HTML, that's why it looks "unformatted". If your input isn't actually HTML, you want to send it as `text/plain`. If your input actually *is* HTML, something seems to be stripping off the tags.

Comment: @Kris Honestly, I don't know what's the difference. It's supposed to be a simple HTML mail, basically. Sorry, I'm totally new to all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying `.format()` to `msg.as_string()` seems extremely brittle. At this point, `msg` should contain a properly MIME-encoded message which might not contain your format strings at all any longer (for example, if the content requires base64 encoding, it will not look at all like your input).  Apply the formatting at an earlier point in the process.

```py
def sendMail(recipient, recipientName):
    with open('~/mail{0}.txt'.format(name), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        data = file.read()
        msg = MIMEText(data.format(recipientName), 'html', 'utf-8')
    mail = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(ip, port)
    mail.login(mailUser, mailPassword)
    mail.sendmail(mailHost, recipient, msg.as_string())
    mail.quit()
```